# qualifiedByName mapstruct, I don't understand why this exception appears?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {
    //qualifiedByName take the
    @Mapping(source = "employee", target = "fullName", qualifiedByName = "fullNameByFirstAndLastName")
    EmployeeDto toDto(Employee employee);
    //do the Inverse of the toDto method
    @InheritInverseConfiguration(name = "toDto")
    Employee fromDto(EmployeeDto dto);
    //take the same source emp
    @Named("fullNameByFirstAndLastName")
    default String fullNameByFirstAndLastName(Employee employee) {
        return employee.getFirstname() + "-" + employee.getLastname();
    }
    /**
     * recommended
     * we can change the interface to abstract class and the methods also
     */
}
@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}
@Data
public class EmployeeDto {
    private int id;
    private String fullName;//FirstName+ ' ' +lastName
}
```

- Unknown property "employee" in result type Employee.EmployeeBuilder. Did you mean "null"?
  -this code isn't compile i want to concatenate the firstname with the mastname in the fullname in EmployeDtO.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
as mentioned by Filip in the comments this should be fixed from 1.5.0.Final onwards, see https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2356.
But you will still need to create manual mappings for the `firstname` and `lastname` fields.

---

The cause is that you inverse inherit the mapping for the field `fullName`.
`@Mapping(source = "employee", target = "fullName", qualifiedByName = "fullNameByFirstAndLastName")` inversed becomes `@Mapping(source = "fullName", target = "employee", qualifiedByName = "fullNameByFirstAndLastName")`.

Because this makes no sense because since you do not have a field named `employee` mapstruct gives that error.

In this situation you cannot make use of the `@InheritInverseConfiguration` route. Instead you will need to write out the reverse mappings yourself.

Which means that

```java
    //qualifiedByName take the
    @Mapping(source = "employee", target = "fullName", qualifiedByName = "fullNameByFirstAndLastName")
    EmployeeDto toDto(Employee employee);
    //do the Inverse of the toDto method
    @InheritInverseConfiguration(name = "toDto")
    Employee fromDto(EmployeeDto dto);
```

will become something like

```
    //qualifiedByName take the
    @Mapping(source = "employee", target = "fullName", qualifiedByName = "fullNameByFirstAndLastName")
    EmployeeDto toDto(Employee employee);
    //do the Inverse of the toDto method
    @Mapping(source = "fullName", target = "firstname", qualifiedByName = "extractFirstNameFromFullName")
    @Mapping(source = "fullName", target = "lastname", qualifiedByName = "extractLastNameFromFullName")
    Employee fromDto(EmployeeDto dto);
    // methods here to extract the first/last name from the fullname.
```

Comment: The fact that the inverse mapping is not part of the target doesn't mean that you can't use it. There used to be a bug that was causing this. However, that has been fixed in newer versions